Looking to skip over specific "subfolder" when using list_objects_v2 in AWS Lambda Function
I have a AWS Lambda function that will "move" objects in my S3 bucket to another location in the same bucket (changes the key) after a certain amount of time. I have this location, the archive, set with a life cycle configuration to save cost. This hasn't been an issue previously, but as more objects have been added, the 'list_objects_v2' call is taking more time. This is the structure of my bucket:
111    
└───folder1
│   │   file011.png
│   │   file012.png
│   
└───folder2
    │   file021.png
    │   file022.png
|
222    
└───folder3
│   │   file031.png
│   │   file032.png
│   
└───folder4
    │   file041.png
    │   file042.png
|
archive    
└───111
│   │   folder1  //Images contained in these folders
│   │   folder2
│   
└───222
    │   folder3
    │   folder4

It isn't an issue now, but as the archive folder grows, the amount of time it will take to complete the function will increase. I'd like to know if there is a way I can exclude the archive folder when calling 'list_objects_v2' or if there is a better alternative?
For a little more context, I'm using Python 3.12 and boto3. Currently calling 'list_objects_v2' with a paginator to get all objects in the bucket.
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name)


Normally you could list the common prefixes at the base level using Delimiter='/', and only scan through the prefixes you're interested in (or skip the ones you don't want to go into)

I looked into this, but I may have a misunderstanding of the delimiter. Does it not just group subfolders based on the character you provide?

It does.  It'll let you list the "folders" at the base level of the bucket and then you can call list objects for each prefix you find that you want the contents of.

I see what you mean. I'll be calling paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix) for each prefix that's returned from list_objects_v2. I think this will work just fine.

A simple way would be to put the "non-archive" folders inside a folder (eg new/222/folder3/file032.png). You would then only need to list the contents of the new folder, which would skip the listing of the archive folder. Also, I'm not sure why you wish to only move the objects after a particular period of time, but another approach would be to trigger the Lambda function immediately when a new object is created and move it. This way, you never actually need to list the contents of the bucket.

@JohnRotenstein, this was my original idea but company has already been utilizing S3 for other specific purposes based on the sample structure I provided and it's a little too late to change it. We can pull objects outside of the archive folder without having everything from history clutter our request, and newly created objects have to be there at least a week.

In that case, I agree with the other comments. You could first obtain a list of CommonPrefixes by passing a Prefix. Then, call ListObjects for each of the prefixes that aren't the archive folder.
